# How to access crossaccount codecommit without NAT gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

We have set up prod and dev AWS accounts. Codecommit is common for both accounts which are created in the prod account and we are using different branches for prod and dev accounts. We have created two desired VPC endpoints for codecommit in the dev account and trying to access the dev branch from the dev account EC2 (with desired IAM profile) but no fate. Both the account VPC don't have any sort of peering since the service is out of VPC. Please help us to achieve this.

Comment: Refer this guide - [Configure cross-account access to an AWS CodeCommit repository using roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html)

Comment: Hi @AnkushJain, Thanks for the prompt answer. I should have mentioned in the question that we want to do that without any internet access. i.e. without NAT gateway in the private subnet.

Comment: I snipped the [tag:git] tag, as this is a general networking issue, not a Git issue. Get the network working, and Git will work (or at least become involved, at which point you might have a new question).